# Texture Coordinate Node for Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

There is [Noise Texture Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/texture/noise.html) for Geometry Nodes, and, just like [Noise Texture Node for shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html), they accept a vector input which's default value is Generated texture coordinates in both cases. But in shader nodes we have [Texture Coordinate Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html), but what can be used for the Geometry Nodes? I'd like to take these generated coordinates and slightly adjust them.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254256/geometry-nodes-image-texture-mapping-how-to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Geometry Nodes* there is no comparable node.

In the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#outputs) you can read about *Generated*:

> *Automatically-generated texture coordinates from the vertex positions of the mesh without deformation, keeping them sticking to the surface under animation. Range from 0.0 to 1.0 over the bounding box of the undeformed mesh.*

So this means that this can be easily recreated in *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Recreating each output of the Texture Coordinate node in geometry nodes:

**Generated:** (By @quellenform , [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269707/157965))
[image: Generated coordinates geometry nodes setup]

**Normal:** Use Input > Normal node, when in the face or face corner domain at least.

**UV:** Use Input > Named Attribute, and enter the name of your UV map. (for Blender 3.2+)

**Object:** By default, Input > Position node. To replicate the object field of the Texture Coordinate node use:

[image: Object coordinates geometry nodes setup]

**Camera:** (elaboration [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280305/157965))
[image: Camera coordinates geometry nodes setup]

**Window:** (elaboration [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280305/157965))
[image: Window coordinates geometry nodes setup]

**Reflection:** when in the face or face corner domain:
[image: Reflection coordinates geometry nodes setup]

Comment: "Use Input > Named Attribute" : does not exists in Blender 4.  Any replacement ?