# How limit the Musgrave Texture Effect in the mesh on Geometry Nodes?

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I am new in Blender and I trying to make a "churros" (food) in geometry nodes.

**Are there some way to prevent the musgrave effect in some part of the mesh in geometry nodes?**

**In my case, on tho top of the mesh, I did not want that line was generated.**

I follow this tutorial (in latin spanish) to make the "Churros": https://youtu.be/41MUnBxNCOk

I tried this solution, but this don't solve, unfortunately: [Texture Coordinate Node for Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269690/texture-coordinate-node-for-geometry-nodes)

[image: Mesh with the unwanted lines.]

[image: I wanted top of the mesh stay that way.]

Comment: Please share your blend file with us. The screenshot is not really helpful and does not give enough information about how this thing is constructed. I did look at the tutorial, but I'm afraid the problem is more of a structural one, which simply produces a miserable topology as a result (so shouldn't be your fault, but that of the tutorial's author).

Comment: Hi, quellenform!

Sorry for come back late and thank you for try to help me. I will send the file with the Chris solution already appplied.
It worked, but no perfectly, I will comment the anothers problems that appeared .

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCx5nYC-9xROySd-BhlnPiz4x2i5VtLj/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

for a "smooth" transition, you can e.g. use this node setup:

[image]

---

There are several possibilities to achieve this effect, e.g. you could use the position of the vertices to influence the behaviour, here i just apply the texture to z values lower than a certain value:

[image]

or you could use a vertex group to use musgrave only on the vertex group like this:

[image]

Note: this only works if the mesh was not generated by GN.

or with this node setup the musgrave texture will be applied only if the distance is within a given range to a point:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Chris.

Thank you so much for your helping. You until sended a _gif_ to ilustrate the modification, this effort must to be very appreciated.

So, I tried the 3rd solution, using the _Compare_ operator than the _Less Than_ and work very well, but this generate 2 problem and I will understand if the help ends here because it escape of the main subject.

1. I wanted smooth the transition between the part without and with the Musgrave effect;
2. I created others "Churros" with the _Draw_ tool in _Edit Mode_ and one, because is in horizontal plane, the _Compare_ Operator work wrong.

Comment: If you want to see the Blender project, here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCx5nYC-9xROySd-BhlnPiz4x2i5VtLj/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Hi, Chris.

Thank you for your support, I really appreciate that, but, sorry, I'm stupid a lot in Blender and I need to learn so much to do what I wanted.

I will classified the topic to solutioned with your answer because of your efforts.

Comment: Hi Mat. Thanks. Don’t think or say that. Geometry nodes is quite complicated especially in the beginning. And if you are not familiar with these „node thing“ and how geometry nodes calculates its values - it is hard to understand. But if you keep watching GN tutorials e.g. from Erindale, you will learn more and more and one day you will understand a lot and think: ha, wasn’t that difficult 

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the materials used for the ends.
Select all the polygons that you don't want the material on. Create a new material and assign them to it. Change the material to the existing churrro material.
In object mode, make the new material a separate user by clicking on the number next to the material name.
You now have a copy of the original material but any changes won't affect the original one.
you can remove your displacement and try to find another texture that works.

Also UV unwrapping the ends would help too. Plenty of tutorials to be found for UVs

Your churro looks great by the way :D

Comment: ...unfortunately this will not work, because we are talking about *Geometry Nodes* here. Have you watched the tutorial?

Comment: Hi, elCamsterino!

Thank you for help me, but, how the quellenform commented, I am using the Geometry Nodes and not Modeling the Mesh. But anyway, I appreciate you help!