Turn textures to materials?
I wonder if it's possible to automatically turn a texture mapped model into a material mapped model.
Manual approach:

Create a new material for each color in the texture,
select model,
enter Edit Mode,
manually select each object face and assign the previously created materials.

Is it possible to make blender do this for me?
Ie. take this picture and its texture (below) and assume that I'd like to turn each color present on the texture to a new material, and then assign it to the model on the same faces where the texture color was mapped.
It's fine if I have to manually select the Base color and all the other stuff for each material: I am trying to avoid to manually select every face in edit mode and reassign it to a different material.
The final goal is to export an FBX made of different materials for a prototype game where I have to dynamically change materials. Thank you



That's not possible without extensions (AFAIK). Also, note that with your proposition you can have multiple colors (thus materials) on one face : how do you manage that ? One face can only have one material.

I was thinking to something that could remap a texture to materials by selecting regions on the texture, and then apply those materials to the mapped faces. I could also use an extension if that exists :)

I think it's possible, but you need to manually set a list of materials and a list of material colors. You add a texture node with the coordinates as input (coordinates from here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269690/texture-coordinate-node-for-geometry-nodes ). Sample the color for the center of the face position, calculate the distances from the color list to find the nearest color and set material to the corresponding material index. (I just don't have the time to experiment now)

Thank you Daniel this seems to be promising! Unfortunately I am not an expert in blender: I have to learn a bunch of stuff before even trying to do this.. :) getting my hands dirty now
